# PHP: put_file_content not working

Tags: php, pdf, birt

I have a php-script which saves a pdf from a eclipse birt report to pdf.
I'm using get file content as imput.
The birt report pdf takes some time to create.

I think this is the problem.

In the following, the script:

```
<?php
$rname = 'reportname';
$wname = $rname . '_' . date('d.m.Y') . '.pdf';
$pdf = file_get_contents("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.x:8080/Birt/run?__report=" . $rname . ".rptdesign&sample=my+parameter&__format=pdf");
file_put_contents('/tmp/report' . $wname, $pdf);
?>
```

What is the problem?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking if `$pdf` actually contains pdf data? checked the return value from `file_get_contents()`? none of your code makes ANY allowance for the real world: things fail, and you're just assuming nothing ever will.

Comment: The problem is, nothing has changed...
For approx. two weeks, the pdf is working.

Comment: The default timeout for HTTP calls in PHP is 60 seconds. If the pdf generation was taking longer than that, then the file_get_contents would end up with no data. If it has gotten faster, then it would suddenly start succeeding. In any case, see @Daniel Lichtenberg's answer for how to override that timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set a request timeout for file_get_contents

```
file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, stream_context_create(Array("http" => Array("method"  => "GET", 
    "timeout" => 600, 
    ))));
```

Also check the default timeout

```
echo ini_get("default_socket_timeout");
```

Answer (score 0):

`file_put_contents()` will return a numeric value (representing bytes written) if it succeeded with writing, and will return `false` when the write was not successful.  If the write is not successful, the web server might not have permission to write to the directory.  Make sure the directory is writable.

```
$result = file_put_contents('/tmp/report' . $wname, $pdf);

if( is_numeric($result) && $result > 0 ) {
    // write was successful
} else {
    // write was NOT successful
}
```

Relevant PHP doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: The permission is correct, but i think, there is a timeout from php get file content... the generating of the report takes approx. 10 minutes